# Changing Atlassian Bitbucket path

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, bitbucket

My setup: I'm running both
Jira and `Bitbucket [5.12.0]` on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. I've tried to change the urls for both apps to be: `192.168.1.77:8080/jira` and `192.168.1.77:7990/bitbucket` respectively.

I've got an Apache webserver setup on another machine that redirects traffic to these machines (using `proxypass` and `proxypassreverse`) as such:

```
 ProxyPassReverse /jira http://192.168.1.77:8080/jira
 ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket http://192.168.1.77:7990/bitbucket
 ProxyPass /jira http://192.168.1.77:8080/jira
 ProxyPass /bitbucket http://192.168.1.77:7990/bitbucket
```

For Jira, I've updated `server.xml` (docBase path property) and set it to `/jira`

As a result, `myserver.com/jira` now works!

However I can't get my Bitbucket instance to launch under `192.168.1.77:7990/bitbucket`. Instead, it is only available under `192.168.1.77:7990`

I have updated the 'Base URL' under 'Server Settings' to `www.myserver.com/bitbucket`. The redirection isn't the problem as it is correctly redirected to `192.168.1.77:7990/bitbucket` - but I get an "**oops, you've found a dead link**" from bitbucket.

I have read a ton of documents and every site says that just updating Base URL should work - so why does it not work for me?

Update:
When I try to change ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse for Bitbucket to the following:

```
ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket http://192.168.1.77:7990
ProxyPass /bitbucket http://192.168.1.77:7990
```

It forwards fine to the Bitbucket login page. However, it appears without images and formatting - like folder permissions are incorrect or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what I was missing.

For some reason, the `server.context-path` was not being added or set in the `bitbucket.properties` file - even when I was changing it through the **Base Path** property under **Server Settings** in the UI.

All I had in that file was the jdbc driver details. Here is the link I followed:
[Moving Bitbucket Server to a different context path](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/moving-bitbucket-server-to-a-different-context-path-779171200.html)

Steps I took:

1. Stopped Bitbucket
2. Edited .../shared/bitbucket.properties to include line: `server.context-path=/bitbucket
3. Restarted Bitbucket

And it now works!